# Testing custom descendant of AbstractController:Base with RSpec

Tags: rspec, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3

I wonder how to test my custom controllers, inherited from AbstractController::Base. I use this to generate some test messages in the context of rake tasks.

What is the best way to test such a code with RSpec? Should I stick to ordinary unit tests or I can use some additional functionality of RSpec controller examples?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I ended up doing normal specs, what requires you to put another name in the `describe`, otherwise rspec knows it's a controller and will try to call some undefined methods in it (because rspec controller tests are actually made for ActionController::Base and not AbstractController::Base)

Good luck!